# Update matplotlib plot correctly - tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Evening,

I want to insert a data point externally into an existing plot (f(x) = x, g(x) = x**2). To do this, the x and y coordinates can be entered in entry fields. The user can then press a button to insert the point.

Assuming a data point (x1, y1) is inserted and the user trys to enter a new data point (x2,y2). In this case the GUI should only display the curves (f(x), g(x)) and the point (x2, y2). The last point (x1,y1) should be deleted.

My solution only partially works: Additional points (x,y) can be created, but the old ones are not deleted...

Does any of you know an approach to solve the problem described above.

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

fig = Figure(figsize = (9, 6), facecolor = "white")

axis = fig.add_subplot(111)
x_values = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
axis.plot(x_values, x_values, "-r")
axis.plot(x_values, x_values ** 2, "--g")
axis.grid()

root = tk.Tk()

Label(root, text = "x =" ).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Label(root, text = "y =" ).grid(row = 1, column = 0)

x = DoubleVar()
y = DoubleVar()

x_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = x).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
y_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = y).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

def plotgraphs():
    axis.plot(x.get(), y.get(), "ko")

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = root)
    canvas._tkcanvas.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

Button(root, text = "New Graphs", command = plotgraphs).grid(row = 0, column = 2)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = root)
canvas._tkcanvas.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete existing point to get the desired behavior. Below would do - what you are looking for. I did enhanced it a bit.

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *

fig = Figure(figsize = (9, 6), facecolor = "white")

axis = fig.add_subplot(111)
x_values = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
axis.plot(x_values, x_values, "-r", label = 'f(X) = x')
axis.plot(x_values, x_values ** 2, "--g", label = 'f(x) = x\N{SUPERSCRIPT TWO}')
axis.grid()
axis.legend()
root = tk.Tk()

Label(root, text = "x =" ).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Label(root, text = "y =" ).grid(row = 1, column = 0)

x = DoubleVar()
y = DoubleVar()

x_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = x).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
y_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = y).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

def plotgraphs():
    if (len(axis.lines)) == 3: # Count existing plotted lines and delete if already existing
        del (axis.lines[2])
        axis.plot(x.get(), y.get(), "ko", label = 'Input point')
    else:
        axis.plot(x.get(), y.get(), "ko", label = 'Input point')
    axis.legend()
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = root)
    canvas._tkcanvas.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

Button(root, text = "New Graphs", command = plotgraphs).grid(row = 0, column = 2)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = root)
canvas._tkcanvas.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```